# Retrieving multiple questions and answers from a database and inserting the answers back in

Tags: php, database, loops

I'm trying to create a poll with several questions which all has multiple options as answers. Both the questions and options are stored in the database. These are in their seperate tables and are joined in a third table that describes the relation between them, like which options belong to which questions.

For now I'm sending queries to the database that retrieves a single question a long with the options for this question. This data is placed in a form with a submit button and an action file attached to it. When the submit button is clicked, the answers are stored rightfully in the database.

When I change the $_SESSION['id'] the question with that id is rightfully shown with the options for that question.

My problem is that I have no clue how to make it display multiple questions along with their options. Either all the questions should be shown along with their options on one page, or you should be able to click next when you've answered one question. I've been trying to put it all into a for loop but without success.

My index.php looks like this

```
   <?php
   session_start();
   $_SESSION['id'] = 1;

    include('dbconfig.php');

        $query = "SELECT * 
        FROM question
        INNER JOIN question_options
        ON question.question_id = question_options.question_id
        INNER JOIN options
        ON options.options_id = question_options.options_id
        WHERE question_options.question_id = ".$_SESSION['id'];
        $result_question = mysqli_query($dbc,$query);
        $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result_question);

        echo $row['question_text'];
?>

<br>

<form id="form" method="post" name="formsub" action="answers.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">

<?php

$qry = "SELECT * 
        FROM question
        INNER JOIN question_options
        ON question.question_id = question_options.question_id
        INNER JOIN options
        ON options.options_id = question_options.options_id
        WHERE question_options.question_id = ".$_SESSION['id'];
        $results = mysqli_query($dbc,$qry);

   while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($results)): ?>
      <!-- Echo out values {id} and {name}   -->
      <input type="radio" name="options" value="<?php echo $row['options_id']; ?> "><?php echo $row['options_text'] . '<br />'; ?>
    <?php endwhile; ?>

<input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Næste" id="submitBtn" class="btn btn-default"/>
</form>
```

The action file looks like this

```
<?php 
session_start();
    include('dbconfig.php');

    $options = $_POST['options'];

$query = "INSERT INTO answer (answer_id, question_id, options_id) VALUES ('NULL', '".$_SESSION['id']."', '".$options."')";
mysqli_query($dbc,$query);

?>
```

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

```php
// fetch questions from db
$questionsSql = "SELECT * FROM question"; // add your WHERE conditions
$questions = $dbc->query($questionsSql)->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);

// create comma separated string with question ids
$questionIds = array_column($questions, 'question_id');
$questionIdsString = implode(',', $questionIds);

// fetch related options from db
$optionsSql = "
    SELECT o.*, qo.question_id
    FROM options o
    INNER JOIN question_options qo
    ON qo.option_Id = o.option_id
    WHERE qo.question_id IN ({$questionIdsString})
";
$options = $dbc->query($optionsSql)->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);

// assign options to questions
foreach ($options as $option) {
    $question['options'][] = $option;
}
```

Now you have a nested array structure with questions and the related options. You will need nested loops to render the form:

```php
foreach ($questions as $question) {
    // print question
    foreach ($question['options'] as $option) {
        // print radio button for the option
    }
}
```